# R - my script is not prompting me to choose a file

Tags: r

When I run my code line by line in the terminal, it works. But when I hit 'Run' on the script - I get this error

`Error in ss.ca.cp(FMax, LSL = 370, USL = 430) : object 'FMax' not found` 
Here is my script:

```
library(readxl)
    
FMax <- read_xlsx(file.choose(), col_names =FALSE, range = "C14:C68")
FMax= as.matrix(FMax)
   
#Import SixSigma package
library(SixSigma)
    
# Get the Z (sigma score) of the process
ss.ca.z(FMax, LSL = 370, USL = 430)
    
# Get the Cp indices of the process
ss.ca.cp(FMax, LSL = 370, USL = 430)
    
# Get the Cp indices confidence intervals
ss.ca.cp(FMax, LSL = 370, USL = 430, ci = TRUE)
    
# Get the Cpk indices of the process
ss.ca.cpk(FMax, LSL = 370, USL = 430)
    
# Get the Cpk indices confidence intervals
ss.ca.cpk(FMax, LSL = 370, USL = 430, ci = TRUE)
    
# Perform process capability analysis
ss.study.ca(FMax,LSL = 370,USL = 430, Target = 400, alpha = 0.05, f.na.rm = TRUE, f.sub = "Process capability")
```

Comment: You probably had that line highlighted or chosen somehow, so the earlier lines didn't run, only that line did.

Comment: I used Control L to clear the console and there isn't anything in the environment. I closed out of Rstudio and re-opened it. Not sure how else to un-highlight or un-select?

Comment: If you mouse over the `Run` button in RStudio, it says "Run the current line or selection"--not the whole script. If nothing is selected it will just run whatever line your cursor is on. So you could Select All and then hit the `Run` button. Or you could use the `Source` button which does run the whole script. What's visible in your console history is irrelevant.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I'm just a bit rusty on this stuff and I haven't used R before.